# predict values from brm

Tags: r, predict, brms

I have a `brm` model that I'd like to generate predicted values for a fixed value of one parameter (length). I think I need to do this with the `posterior_predict` function (or possibly the `posterior_epred` function), but these functions both generate large matrices with no labels so it's impossible to know what is actually being generated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(brms)
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(mass   = rnorm(100, mean = 50, sd = 5),
                 length = rnorm(100, mean = 20, sd = 2),
                 sex    = sample(c("f", "m"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 site   = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE))

m <- brm(mass ~ length * sex + site, data = df, prior = prior(normal(0, 10)))

newdata <- data.frame(site   = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 30),
                      sex    = rep(c("f", "m"), 45),
                      length = 20)
pred1 <- bind_cols(newdata, predict(m, newdata)) # results in a usable dataframe
pred2 <- posterior_predict(m, newdata)           # results in a large matrix with no labels
pred3 <- posterior_epred(m, newdata)             # results in a large matrix with no labels

ggplot(data = pred1, aes(x = Estimate, y = site, col = sex)) + geom_violin()
```

[image]

Comment: Both pred1 and pred2 are 4000 rows x 90 columns. By default brms gives you 1000 posterior samples each from 4 Markov chains, for 4000 total. Hence the number of rows. The 90 columns correspond to the 90 rows in newdata. The difference between `posterior_predict` and `posterior_epred` is explained in the documentation (sort of like the difference between a prediction interval and confidence interval of the mean, in a frequentist analysis).

Comment: If you want output that is easier to work with in tidyverse, look into the tidybayes package, in particular the functions `add_predicted_draws` and `add_epred_draws` which give "tidy" versions of the two different types of posterior predictions.

Comment: @qdread, I think my frustration with posterior_predict is that I have no idea what value corresponds to the data in newdata.

Comment: @qdred, add_predicted_draws seems like it will be helpful for this particular question, but it doesn't provide the CIs that I'd get with the predict function.

Comment: Try `newdata |> add_predicted_draws(m) |> median_qi()` . This will give 95% equal tailed credible interval by default but other options are possible

Comment: Thank-you! do you want to write up an answer for me to accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation of `posterior_predict` output

Both `posterior_predict()` and `posterior_epred()` produce a 4000x90 matrix. Why 4000 rows? It has 4000 rows because the model fit by `brm()` uses an MCMC algorithm to sample the joint posterior distribution of the parameters. By default it does this with four Markov chains that return 1000 samples each, for a total of 4000. Why 90 columns? Because `newdata` in this case has 90 rows. The columns of `pred1` and `pred2` correspond to the rows of `newdata`, in the same order.

Incidentally the difference between `posterior_predict()` and `posterior_epred()` is similar to the difference between a prediction interval and a confidence interval around the mean in a frequentist analysis. `posterior_predict()` gives you draws from the posterior predictive distribution, which incorporates the residual error and thus has higher variance. In contrast `posterior_epred()` gives you the distribution of the expected value of the posterior.

### Solution without any additional packages

To get a median and a 95% equal-tailed credible interval of the posterior predictive distribution for each row in `newdata` you could do this:

```
posteriorpredictive_CI <- bind_cols(
  newdata,
  t(apply(pred2, 2L, quantile, probs = c(.5, .025, .975)))
)
```

### Additional solution using **tidybayes** package

You may find the **tidybayes** package makes this easier. The functions `add_predicted_draws()` (for the posterior predictive distribution) and `add_epred_draws()` (for the expected value of the posterior) output long-form "tidy" data frames. These have 360,000 rows because each row of `newdata` is repeated 4000 times, one for each of the posterior draws. Then the function `median_qi()`, imported from **ggdist** which is a dependency of **tidybayes**, can be used to summarize with equal-tailed credible intervals. This will give you similar results to the previous code, with some extra ID columns identifying the width of the interval and which row of `newdata` each row of the summary comes from.

```
library(tidybayes)

posteriorpredictive_CI <- newdata |>
  add_predicted_draws(m) |>
  median_qi()
```

The width of the interval is 0.95 by default but can be changed with the `.width` argument of `median_qi()`.